# how to generate session id on Java EE by myself

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to generate session id on `Java EE` by my self. Such as I want to generate session id 128 bit, 256 bit,

How to generate it?

Answer (score 4):

Session ID is generated by application server. So, it depends in it. To do this you have to change your application server (I mean create some patch to it).

I believe you can do this but you have to discover each application server separately. So, you will not be able to deploy your application on sever without your patch. It means that this technique does not seem as optimal.

And the biggest question here is "why"? I believe you should better explain your cause problem. I believe that guys here can suggest you a better solution.